# rhandsontable no se actualiza al usar selectizeGroupUI

Tags: r, update, shiny

Estoy creando una aplicación de Shiny que muestra una tabla de rhandsontable diferente para cada opción de radioButton ("A", "B"). Esta aplicación incluye un modulo de filtrado de dos variables ("Petal.Width", "Species"). El problema es que la tabla no se actualiza cuando cambia las opciones de selectizeGroupUI. Ejemplo: filtrando por Species= "versicolor" y viendo ambas tablas, las tablas se ven así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando cambiamos el filtro Species, la tabla que estamos viendo actualmente se actualiza, pero cuando cambiamos la opción del radioButton, esta nueva tabla no se actualiza.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(rhandsontable)
library(DT)


data1 <- iris %>% mutate(Petal.Width = if_else(iris$Petal.Width>0.4, ">0.4", "<=0.4")) %>% 
  select("Petal.Width", "Species", "Petal.Length")

data1 <- data1[c(1:3,44,51:53,102:105),]

data2 <- iris %>% mutate(Petal.Width = if_else(iris$Petal.Width>0.4, ">0.4", "<=0.4")) %>% 
  select("Petal.Width", "Species", "Sepal.Length")

data2 <- data2[c(1:3,44,51:53,102:105),]

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "black",
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Aranceles",
    titleWidth = 200,
    uiOutput("logoutbtn")
  ),
  
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE),
  
  dashboardBody(
    
    fluidRow(
      tabBox(
        height = "2100px",
        width = 12,
        selected = "Tab1",
        
               
        tabPanel("Tab1",
                 
                 fluidRow(column(
                   width = 6,
                   selectizeGroupUI(
                     id = "my-filters1",
                     inline = TRUE,
                     params = list(
                       Petal.Width= list(
                         inputId = "Petal.Width",
                         title = "Petal.Width"
                       ),
                       Species = list(
                         inputId = "Species",
                         title = "Species"
                     )))),
                 
                 fluidRow(
                   basicPage(
                     radioButtons(
                       inputId = "value",
                       choices = list("A", "B"),
                       label = "label"
                     ))),
                 
                 fluidRow(basicPage(uiOutput('table')))
      ))
  )
)))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_reac1<- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "my-filters1",
    data = data1,
    vars = c("Petal.Width","Species")
  )
  
  data_reac2<- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "my-filters1",
    data = data2,
    vars = c("Petal.Width","Species")
  )
  
  
  rv_data1 <- reactiveValues(table_rv1 = NULL)
  
  observeEvent((input$value == "A" & 
                  ((is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) | 
                     (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) |
                     (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) |
                     (is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])))) || 
                 (input$value == "B" & 
                    ((is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) | 
                       (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) |
                       (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) | 
                       (is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])))),{
                         data_reac1.1 <- data_reac1() %>%
                           mutate("new_var" = 0) 
                         rv_data1$table_rv1<- data_reac1.1})
  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$table1)){
      mytable_rv1 <- as.data.frame(hot_to_r(input$table1))
      mytable_rv1[,4] <- (mytable_rv1[,3]*2)
      rv_data1$table_rv1 <- mytable_rv1}
  })
  
  table_1.1 <- reactive({
    rhandsontable(rv_data1$table_rv1)
  })
  
  
  rv_data2 <- reactiveValues(table_rv2 = NULL)
  
  observeEvent((input$value == "A" & 
                  ((is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) | 
                     (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) |
                     (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) |
                     (is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])))) || 
                 (input$value == "B" & 
                    ((is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) | 
                       (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) |
                       (!is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])) | 
                       (is.null(input[["my-filters1-Species"]]) & !is.null(input[["my-filters1-Petal.Width"]])))),{
                         data_reac2.1 <- data_reac2() %>%
                           mutate("new_var" = 0) 
                         rv_data2$table_rv2<- data_reac2.1})
  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$table2)){
      mytable_rv2 <- as.data.frame(hot_to_r(input$table2))
      mytable_rv2[,4] <- (mytable_rv2[,3]+10)
      rv_data2$table_rv2 <- mytable_rv2}
  })
  
  table_2.1 <- reactive({
    rhandsontable(rv_data2$table_rv2)
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    table_1.1() 
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    table_2.1()
  })
  
  
  output$table <- renderUI({
    if(input$value == "A"){rHandsontableOutput("table1")}
    else{rHandsontableOutput("table2")}})
  
 }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```